# Phantom whitespace when using nested CSS grids

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a HTML `table` of the form:

```
<tr>
  <td class="rune"></td>
  <td class="name">Yggdrasil</td>
  <td class="desc"><p>Space for animals w/ access to greenspace on the roof.</p></td>
</tr>
⋮
```

There are ten rows and I am trying to display two per line with a double column of runes down the middle. The SCSS that I have so far is:

```
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;

  tr {
    display: grid;
    width: 50%;
  }

  .rune {
    font-size: 17em;
  }

  .name {
    text-align: center;
  }

  tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 12em;

    .rune {
      grid-column: 2 / end;
      grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }

    .name {
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      grid-row: 1 / 2;
    }

    .desc {
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      grid-row: 2 / 3;
    }
  }

  tr:nth-child(2n) {
    grid-template-columns: 12em 1fr;

    .rune {
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }

    .name {
      grid-column: 2 / end;
      grid-row: 1 / 2;
    }

    .desc {
      grid-column: 2 / end;
      grid-row: 2 / 3;
    }
  }
}
```

But, as you can see in [this pen](https://codepen.io/dysbulic/pen/vYYQYvw), the positions of the runes is correct, but there is what seems to be a phantom column adding space at the end of each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I had a `width: 50%` lingering from a pre-grid version. [It works now.](https://z13cdn.web.app/map)